# Checking a mac can talk to a Domain Controller

Tags: windows, networking, active-directory, domain-controller

I would like to know a series of steps that could be checked before binding a Mac to a Domain. I'm not sure how the client communicates with the DC but I'm happy to read if someone can point me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 3):

Although it is possible for an OSX box to talk to an AD DC via LDAP I'd suggest spending a bit of money and pickup a copy of Thursby's excellent [ADmitMac](http://www.thursby.com/products/admitmac.html) software - it makes it super easy and stable.

Comment: I'm curious. What does it do to already-established local accounts on the Mac? I'd love to be able to integrate the Mac laptops in my environment into the AD, but would it require major profile changes?

Comment: Thanks, we are aware of the product ranges out there but this was no the original question. I want to write a tool that can test the communication between a client and a Domain Controller.

Answer (score 2):

Should you opt not to use the ADmitMac software, there is a metric ton of Mac-Windows integration info at [MacWindows.com](http://macwindows.com/), including how to bind to the domain using only the Mac's built-in tools.

In our environment, we bound our very few Macs using the Directory Service application (under Applications/Utilties). It asks for domain info, an admin password, what AD groups should be admins on the Mac, and that's gives you network logins with local profiles. For us, that's all we needed.

Comment: I'd certainly go down this route before buying ADmitMac - very good bit of software though it is, I'd say its more "nice to have" than "must have" these days. It was probably essential around and about 10.3 or earlier but somewhere between 10.3 and 10.4 the OSX integration as an AD client improved quite a bit, and we've had no trouble with this kind of thing at all with leopard/snow leopard.

Comment: The ADPlugin is suitable for our needs, and this is our current configuration. Again perhaps I was unclear with my original message. I want to write a tool to test communication between a client and the domain controller.